# JSON data not being displayed through innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use vanilla Javascript to get data from my JSON file and insert it in HTML.
But my code keeps displaying the variable name instead of the data.

```
displayProducts(products){
let result = "";
products.forEach(product => {
  result +="<article class='product'><div class='img-container'><img src=${product.image} alt='oops' class='product-img'><button class='bag-btn' data-id=${product.id}><img src='./images/poopbag.png'>Add to bag</button></div><h3>${product.title}</h3><h4>$${product.price}</h4></article>";
});
productsDOM.innerHTML=result;
```

}

What is being displayed is ${product.image} , ${product.id}, and ${product.title}.
Not the actually data.
When i put console.log(product.image), console.log(product.id), and console.log(product.title) in the same function, it shows the data i want.

Comment: You are using a normal string, you need a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to use the `${variable}` syntax.

Comment: it worked, THANK YOU for the quick response!

Answer (score 2):

String interpolation requires you to use backticks `` ` `` instead of single quote `'` or double quote `"`.

```
`<article class='product'><div class='img-container'><img src=${product.image} alt='oops' class='product-img'><button class='bag-btn' data-id=${product.id}><img src='./images/poopbag.png'>Add to bag</button></div><h3>${product.title}</h3><h4>$${product.price}</h4></article>`
```